# How to parse json result of syncfusion diagram control dynamically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, serialization

I've used diagram control in my `ASP.NET` application and I could use save and load method in my app. Now I need to parse  `json` result of diagram control without statically creating C# class for it's key values because this diagram created dynamically.

I wanna identify all keys with their values in diagram in my server side code. Hence I force to parse `json` result of diagram in save method.

this is my C# class :

```
 public class Product
    {
        public string Name;
        public DateTime Expiry;
        public decimal Price;
        public string[] Sizes;

    }
```

and this is my pars method

```
public static void ParsJson(string jsonContent)
  {
     Product deserializedProduct = 
               JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(jsonContent);
  }
```

and this is json Content :

```
   {
      "Name": "Apple",
      "Expiry": "2008-12-28T00:00:00",
      "Price": 3.99,
      "Sizes": [
        "Small",
        "Medium",
        "Large"
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

First use the following package:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

Then, write the following code:

```
dynamic deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
```

Comment: You dont need to pass `<dynamic>`. See my example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [json helper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.json%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) :

```
dynamic data = Json.Decode(jsonContent);
```

Full example using Json.Net with working [online demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Vhq3bq) :

```
var jsonContent = @"{
    'Name': 'Apple',
    'Expiry': '2008-12-28T00:00:00',
    'Price': 3.99,
    'Sizes': [
        'Small',
        'Medium',
        'Large'
    ]
}";
dynamic product = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonContent);
Console.WriteLine(product.Name);
```

output :

```
Apple
```